# Multiple Websites - which data is shared?

Tags: multistore

I need your help.

I want to create a second store in my current Magento setup. I want to use this second store only in the backend, because b2b orders are inserted manually. Usually I can switch between different views in Magento to only view the data for a specific store view (e.g in the products section this is the case)

I am bit confused now, because I set up a second website, with a store and storeview. The storeview is set to Status to "Deactivated" because I will not use it on the frontend.

Questions:

1. However, when I see it correctly the orders and customers are showed in the backend for both Websites. I can select a customer which has been registered in the B2C Store and insert an order for the b2b store. The orders are also shown together regardless if they have been placed for website 1 or website 2. Is this correct, that two websites share customer and order data?
2. I also can use the same catalog of the b2c store (Root Catalog) but have to enter the products twice. Correct? I will have different products in both stores but also some of the b2c products are also available in the b2b store - so I have to enter these products twice, correct?

Thanks for clarification!